# How to determine h(x) in a polynomial partial fraction decompostion

Tags: partial-fractions, rational-functions

Im susposed to do a partial fractional division;

$$ \frac{-2x^2 + 8x - 9} {(x-1) (x-3)^2}$$ Now I used the formula and this is what I got;

$$\frac {A}{(x-1)} + \frac{B}{x-3} + \frac{C}{(x-3)^2}$$

Now I've put the 3 fractions together,and got this

$$ \frac{A(x-3)^2+B(x-3)(x-1) +C(x-1)} {(x-1) (x-3)} $$

Now I looked at the starting function looked what my x^2 ,x terms were on the right on the left, solved it and got this

$$f(x) = \frac{-2} {4(x+1)} + \frac{-5} {4(x-3)} + \frac {3} {2(x-1)^2} $$

Now after looking at the formula I'd realise that I'm missing my h(x) the whole part if you will ( not sure how it is said in english) Now the h(x) doesnt exist when m < n but in my case m = n so I should also be having that? But how do I get that part? the formula says simply h(x) + the A B and C parts.How do I calculate h(x)?

EDIT: To clarify what h(x) means and what I was exactly trying to figure out.

$$f(x) = h(x) + \frac{r(x)} {q(x)}$$

Where m = deg r and n = deg q

Comment: It should be $\frac {-3}{4(x+1)}$; what do you mean by $h(x), m, n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when you put three fractions together:
$$
\frac{A(x-3)^2+B(x-1)(x-3)+C(x-1)}{(x-1)(x-3)^\color{red}{2}}.
$$

Now you set
$$
A(x-3)^2+B(x-1)(x-3)+C(x-1)=-2x^2+8x-9
$$
to find $A,B,C$.

- Set $x=1$: $4A=-2+8-9$.
- Set $x=3$: $2C=-18+24-9$.
- Set $x=2$: $A-B+C=-8+16-9$.

Now it should be very straightforward to go on.

---

Notes.

If you write
$$
f(x)=\frac{-2x^2+8x-9}{(x-1)(x-3)^2}
$$
then you can find polynomials $h,p,q$ so that
$$
f(x)=h(x)+\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
where the $\deg p<\deg q$.
This is the preliminary step for partial fraction decomposition.

But note that
$$
\deg (-2x^2+8x-9)<\deg (x-1)(x-3)^2
$$
you have $h(x)=0$, $p(x)=-2x^2+8x-9$ and $q(x)=(x-1)(x-3)^2$.

Comment: I see but what I am not checking is what Jose is saying. My nummerator is to the power of 2 and my denominator also? But Jose says its 3 but I just dont see it. And by h(x) I mean the whole part of a polynomial division. Also the term that comes up in the formula for partial fraction decompostion.

Comment: @codeisfun: can you please explicitly write out what $h(x)$ is? Is it $h(x)=-2x^2+8x-9$?

Comment: @codeisfun: if you can confirm what $h(x)$ is, it would not be difficult to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: No no im not trying to figure out what is h(x) but why I dont have to FIND it. I dont know how to translate into english what I'm trying to say but when we divide a rational function f(x) = h(x) + p(x)/q(x) we get this;f= h(x) + r(x)/q(x) where h(x) is the part that may or may not exist depending on if m >= n where m is the power of p(x) and where n is the power of q(x)

Comment: @codeisfun: see my edit.

Comment: Excellent, now I think I get it, its just that on the right if we would to multiply (x-1) (x-3)^2 we would get  higher deegre right than left?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118601/discussion-between-mrsamy-and-codeisfun).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but there is some mistake in your computations, since, in fact$$A=-\frac34,\ B=-\frac54\text{, and }C=-\frac32;$$therefore$$\frac{-2x^2+8x-9}{(x-1)(x-3)^2}=-\frac3{4(x-1)}-\frac5{4(x-3)}-\frac3{2(x-3)^2}.$$And, in your case, the degree of the numerator is $2$ and the degree of the denominator is $3$. Therefore, there is nothing else to be done.

Comment: How is A = -3/4, did I do my calculations wrong or is something in the method solving wrong? And how is the denominator 3? it is x-3 squared? Am I missing something?

Comment: You made a mistake whe you've put those fractions together. It should be$$\frac A{x-1}+\frac B{x-3}+\frac C{(x-3)^2}=\frac{Ax^2+Bx^2-6Ax-4Bx+Cx+9A+3B-C}{(x-3)^2(x-1)}.$$

Comment: I actually did It like that I just forgot to put it in LaTeX. I've checked the solutions for A B and C and it turns out I actually made a mistake in A,that was my bad. But still how do I have 2 in the nummerator and 3 in the denominator? Is when I multiply (x-1) and (x-3)^2 i wil get an x^3 value?

Comment: I cannot answer that unless you show your computations in detail.

Comment: Indeed, $A=-3/2$.(One gets this "immediately" by the old engineer's trick without solving a system of equations: multiply the *ansatz* by $(x-1)$, cancel (x-1) on the left side and then let $x=1$.)